# Empty set literal?

Tags: python, set, literals

`[]` = empty `list`

`()` = empty `tuple`

`{}` = empty `dict`

Is there a similar notation for an empty `set`?
Or do I have to write `set()`?

Comment: you don't accept {i for i in []}, didn't you?

Comment: Just want to show nearly anything is possible with python. If you want to create a set without using to set(), you can.

Comment: Yeah, you can do pretty much everything in a hundred convulted ways. I don't add `map(lambda x: x)` to my code examples just to show you it works either. It's not a set literal as well, it's just a set comprehension.

Comment: @utdemir [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: A dumb way which works would be `{0}-{0}`.  It's not as clear as `set()`, but it does have the advantage of looking like a funny pair of eyes.

Comment: @wim How does that work? (I'm just curious, as I mistakenly used `{{}}` to denote an empty `dict(dict())`, and PyCharm mistook it for a set.)

Comment: @Chris `{}` is a dictionary. `{0}` is a set. `{0} - {0}` is the difference between a set and itself, which is the empty set.

Comment: I'm partial to `{*''}`, personally, if only because it resembles a face. (Don't use it seriously, though!)

Comment: @M.I.Wright For some reason, {*''} runs faster on my computer than set()

Comment: @Kade That sounds correct. Function calls are quite slow in Python (largely thanks to stack-manipulation overhead) so a call-less solution is always going to be faster -- cf. `f{a}'` vs `str(a)`. The issue with `{*''}` is simply that the speed gain isn't *really* worth temporarily confusing everybody who reads your code (and microoptimizations hardly ever matter in Python if you're not already using pypy).

Comment: Beware: while ``()`` is a tuple, ``('a string')`` is a string. In the latter, parenthesis just "protect" the content (letting you write expressions on multiple lines without a trailing ``\``). Initialize a tuple with one element by adding a comma: ``('a string', )`` is a tuple of length 1.

Comment: Many answers miss the fact that there is not way to make an empty set valid for `ast.literal_eval()`. `set()` does not work here. For everywhere else, I prefer dict() over {} and list() over []. Why not a PEP to suggest `{/}` as an empty set... or `{,}`

Comment: this has been annoying me as well. empty set *should* be {}, to make it consistent with {0,1,3} being a set. empty dict should be {:}.

Answer (score 688, accepted):

No, there's no literal syntax for the empty set. You have to write [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: You mean there is no literal syntax for the empty set? Or for sets in general?

Comment: There are set literals, but only in Python 3.x. There isn't a literal for empty sets either way.

Comment: @user763305: The language manual is pretty clear on this point.  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset says "non-empty sets ... can be created by placing a comma-separated list of elements within braces"

Comment: Actually, set literals have been backported to Python 2.7, so they are not only available strictly in Python 3.

Comment: @andy That's not an empty set - that's a set containing the number 1. You don't need the trailing comma by the way - that's only required for tuples.

Answer (score 100):

By all means, *please use* `set()` to create an empty set.

But, if you want to impress people, tell them that you can create an empty set using literals and `*` with Python >= 3.5 ([see PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)) by doing:

```
>>> s = {*()}  # or {*{}} or {*[]}
>>> print(s)
set()
```

this is basically a more condensed way of doing `{_ for _ in ()}`, but, don't do this.

Comment: Why?! Performance is almost identical:
`$ python3.7 -m timeit 'set()'
    2000000 loops, best of 5: 177 nsec per loop
    $ python3.7 -m timeit '{*()}'
    2000000 loops, best of 5: 171 nsec per loop`

Comment: @ogurets, `set()` is likely much easier to understand (for code maintainers), and that often matters more than performance. `{*()}` seems "clever" in an almost pejorative sense.

Comment: Heh, that's clever.

Comment: If you want to _impress_ people, you say?

Comment: Say you have a lot of non-empty sets in a file, and you suddenly have to write an empty one (say it's not implemented yet) then it may be better to declare a set this way for consistency.

Comment: What is surprising to me is that an empty `set()` takes 216 bytes whereas an empty `dict()` takes only 64 bytes!

Answer (score 52):

Just to extend the accepted answer:

From version `2.7` and `3.1` python has got `set` literal `{}` in form of usage `{1,2,3}`, but `{}` itself still used for empty dict.

Python 2.7 (first line is invalid in Python <2.7)

```
>>> {1,2,3}.__class__
<type 'set'>
>>> {}.__class__
<type 'dict'>
```

Python 3.x

```
>>> {1,2,3}.__class__
<class 'set'>
>>> {}.__class__
<class 'dict'>
```

More here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is still no literal syntax to represent an empty set. `{}.__class__` would still give `dict`

Comment: @Ninja420 try to read first before comment, i have noticed that

Comment: The accepted answer is still correct, and is not outdated. There is not a literal syntax for *the empty set*, there is however one for the empty dictionary.

Comment: @AndreasBjørn for an empty yes, however for non empty you will get PEP8 exception and suggestion to use set literal.

Comment: actually, `{}.__class__` returns `<class 'dict'>'` with pyt3.6, not `<type 'dict'>`

Answer (score 12):

Yes. The same notation that works for non-empty dict/set works for empty ones.

Notice the difference between non-empty `dict` and `set` literals:

`{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}` -- a number of key-value pairs inside makes a `dict`
`{'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}` -- a number of values inside makes a `set`

So:

`{}` == zero number of key-value pairs == empty `dict`
`{*()}` == empty tuple of values == empty `set`

However the fact, that you can do it, doesn't mean you should. Unless you have some strong reasons, it's better to construct an empty set explicitly, like:

```py
a = set()
```

> #### Performance:
>
> The **literal** is *~15% faster* than the **set**-constructor (CPython-3.8, 2019 PC, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz):
>
> ```py
> >>> %timeit ({*()} & {*()}) | {*()}
> 214 ns ± 1.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>
> >>> %timeit (set() & set()) | set()
> 252 ns ± 0.566 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
> ```
>
> ... and for completeness, *Renato Garcia's* [`frozenset` proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576113/548792) on the above expression is some *60% faster*!
>
> ```py
> >>> ϕ = frozenset()
>
> >>> %timeit (ϕ & ϕ) | ϕ
> 100 ns ± 0.51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
> ```

**NB**: As *ctrueden* noticed in comments, `{()}` is **not** an empty set. It's a set with 1 element: empty tuple.

Comment: `{()}` is not the empty set. It is a singleton set with one element: an empty tuple. You can verify this by checking `len({()})` which will be 1, or `() in {()}`, which will be `True`.

Comment: Oops, you're right! I updated the post: added the note about `{()}` not being an empty set, in case someone else makes the same mistake. Thank you, @ctrueden!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on if you want the literal for a comparison, or for assignment.

If you want to make an existing set empty, you can use the `.clear()` metod, especially if you want to avoid creating a new object.  If you want to do a comparison, use `set()` or check if the length is 0.

example:

```
#create a new set    
a=set([1,2,3,'foo','bar'])
#or, using a literal:
a={1,2,3,'foo','bar'}

#create an empty set
a=set()
#or, use the clear method
a.clear()

#comparison to a new blank set
if a==set():
    #do something

#length-checking comparison
if len(a)==0:
    #do something
```

Comment: `a=set()` does not *empty the set*, but creates a new set and assigns it to `a`, overwriting any previous value.

Comment: Indeed.  That's why I said that if you want to avoid creating a new object, you should use clear().  I suppose my comment should have been worded slightly differently.

Comment: It also appears using the `a.clear()` method is slightly faster than `a=set()`, and checking `len(a)==0` is slightly faster than checking for equality to `a==set()`

Comment: Instead of `if len(a)==0:` it suffices (and is more Pythonic) to write just `if a:`  (edit: or rather, `if not a:` to match the polarity of the condition).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the crazy ideas: with Python 3 accepting unicode identifiers, you could declare a variable `ϕ = frozenset()` (ϕ is U+03D5) and use it instead.

Comment: Problem is, `set` objects are mutable, so you're putting yourself at risk with `spam = ϕ; spam.add("eggs")`.

Comment: if `ϕ` is a frozenset, then `spam.add("eggs")` fails, because the frozenset  object doesn't have any `add` method.

Comment: @BrianMinton: But that is the intended behavior. Note that when someone writes `span = ϕ` both `span` and `ϕ` will point to the same object, i.e. `id(span) == id(ϕ)`. Hence, if `spam.add("eggs")` would work, the `ϕ` object would not be an empty set anymore, and we will come back to the original problem as pointed by drdaeman

Comment: @RenatoGarcia Compare with the empty dict literal: `>>> a={}
>>> a['foo']='bar'
>>> a
{'foo': 'bar'}
`

Comment: Why not use the "empty set" symbol (U+2205)`∅`, instead?

Answer (score -5):

There are few ways to create empty Set in Python :

1. Using [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) method 
   This is the built-in method in python that creates Empty set in that variable.
2. Using clear() method (creative Engineer Technique LOL) 
   See this Example:
    
   sets={"Hi","How","are","You","All"}
   type(sets)  (This Line 
   Output : set)
   sets.clear()
   print(sets)  (This Line Output : {})
   type(sets)  (This Line 
   Output : set)

So, This are 2 ways to create empty Set.