# simple web crawler i need to eliminate the duplicate URL that present in the array

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

i am using the array to store the URL  and i need to eliminate the URL the are present more than once in array because i don't need to crawl the same URL again:

```
self.level = []  # array where the URL are present 
for link in self.soup.find_all('a'):
    self.level.append(link.get('href'))
    print(self.level)
```

i need to eliminate duplicate URL before crawling this URL.

Answer (score 7):

Maintain a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of urls:

```
self.level = set()
for link in self.soup.find_all('a'):
    self.level.add(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: @mans it is just that, by definition, a set is a collection of unique elements.

Comment: can you explain set() method what it is ..?

Comment: @mans it is a way of initializing an empty set, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130374/empty-set-literal-in-python.

Comment: @mans: Please see the Python docs about sets: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset (thanks to P_O_I_S_O_N for suggesting the 1st link).