# Python basics ambiguous notation

Tags: python

T={}

Is T a set or a dictionary?

type(T) returns  dict but isn't it an ambiguous notation? OR am my missing something?
sys.getsizeof(T) gives 148 and I think this is just an anticipation of dict to be on the safer side.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Just because sets in math are in `{}` doesn't mean it should be same way in Python

Comment: It is a little ambiguous, unless you're aware of the history. Python has always had dictionaries, but sets are a relatively late addition to the language, and set literals are even more recent.

Comment: If type(T) tells you that it's a dict, then it's a dict. Why would it lie to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty set literal in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130374/empty-set-literal-in-python)

Comment: This seems like you want a discussion. Stackoverflow was not designed for discussions, but for questions based on facts. If you want a discussion, you could try reddit.com

Comment: It might seem like sets are more fundamental than dicts, but bear in mind that sets are merely a convenient collection type, whereas dicts are vital to Python: they're used for `globals()`, `locals()`, and object attributes (unless the object defines `__slots__`).

Answer (score 1):

It's a dict. Period.
If you want an empty set, use `set()`.

If you want a filled set, you can use either the `{1, 2, 3, 4}` (since Python 3) notation or the `set((1, 2, 3, 4))` notation.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}  # A dictionary
d = dict()  # also a dictionary
s = set()  # A set
```

This is also stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> Curly braces or the set() function can be used to create sets. Note: to create an empty set you have to use set(), not {}; the latter creates an empty dictionary, a data structure that we discuss in the next section.

Especially the examples afterwards make it clear. (To be honest, I'm a bit confused by the "Curly braces [...] can be used to create sets.")

Speculation: The `{}` notation is shorter and dictionarys are more often used. Also, it is a common notation in other languages, too.

One way to think about dictionaries is as a set of (key, value) tuples. Hence the set-like notation does make sense.

Comment: Conversely, a way to think about sets is that they are dicts with keys but no values.

Comment: @PM2Ring I read somewhere that sets were actually originally built this way (as dicts without values) in CPython, is that right?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm not sure about that. However, when I first investigated the CPython source code for the set & dict objects there were a lot of similarities, although I expect that they've since diverged somewhat, since for Python 3.6 some rather radical changes have been made to the dict implementation.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you! That makes sense; and I've just found the text I was referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3949350/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands Nice work. And the changes to how dictobject.c does its hashtable are still very fresh: people were complaining only a few months ago that the comments were no longer in synch with the code, but that's since been fixed. :) See https://bugs.python.org/issue20674 I suppose we really need to ask one of the core devs, maybe [Raymond Hettinger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) himself, to get the full story...