# How to store many inputs from a user in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, set

My aim is to have many inputs from a user stored in a disordered manner. So, I decided to use a `set`. The code I have so far is:

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
d = input()

all = a, b, c, d
print(set(all))
```

However, I do not want to repeat `input()` several times like above. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

If all you want is a `set` you do not need `a, b, c, d`.

```
all = set()   #or all = {*(),}
for _ in range(4):
    all.add(input())

print(all)
```

Or,

```
all = {input() for _ in range(4)}
```

This is considering you take the inputs in new line. Otherwise, if the input are comma-separated for example:

```
all = set(input().split(','))
print(all)
```

or

```
all = {*input().split(',')}
print(all)
```

In case you need both `a, b, c, d` and all the inputs, you could do:

```
>>> all = a, b, c, d = {*input().split(',')}
# example
>>> all = a, b, c, d = {1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> all
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

As pointed out by [@Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136212/how-to-store-many-user-input-in-a-python-set/60136251#comment106360567_60136251) `all(iterable)` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) avoid naming your variables same as python builints or keywords.
Another point, if in case you have already done so, in order to get the default behavior of all, you could do:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> all = builtins.all
# Or, more conveniently, as pointed out by @Martijn Pieters
>>> del all
```

- `*` is used for [`iterable unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)
- `_` is used for `don't care` or `throwaway` or `anonymous variable`,
  as we do not need the variable in the loop. More on this
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/5431791).
- [`{*()}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180500/5431791) is just a fancy way of creating empty sets as python does not have empty set literals. It is recommended to use `set()`

Comment: Instead of rebinding the global, just *delete it*: `del all`. Built-ins are a separate namespace.

Answer (score 9):

You could put your calls to input() in a comprehension:

```
set(input() for i in range(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop:

```
all = set()
for _ in range(4):
  all.add(int(input())
print(all)
```

Don't forget that input gives you a string, so you should convert it to int or any type if needed excplicitly.

"_" in the for loop means that this variable is not important. But you can put whatever name you like.